# How to update text when using mouseMoveMethod?

Tags: javascript, text, mousemove

I'm new to programming and take Javascript as a school course. I have come upon this problem, and have been stuck because I have been unable to update the text; for instance, when I move my mouse over the canvas, it just overlaps the text. Is there any solution to updating text, or am I just missing something basic?

```
/* This program displays the x and y
 * coordinates in a label on the screen
 * and updates when the mouse moves */

function start(){
    mouseMoveMethod(drawCoordinates);

}

function drawCoordinates(e){
    var txt = new Text(e.getX(), "15pt Arial");
    var text = new Text(e.getY(), "15pt Arial");
    txt.setPosition(100, 100);
    txt.setColor(Color.black);
    add(txt);
    text.setPosition(100, 200);
    text.setColor(Color.black);
    add(text);
}
```

Comment: Can you create a working example of jsfiddle.net for us to see in action?

Comment: Please create a working __fiddle__.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a new Text every time the drawCoordinates method executes.
If this was browser based, you'd need something like this...

```
function drawCoordinates(e){
    //Check if we can find the lable for X first.
    //If we can't, create a new one....

    var txt = document.getElementById('txtX');
    if(txt==null)
    {
        txt = new Text(e.getX(), "15pt Arial");
        txt.setPosition(100, 100);
        txt.setColor(Color.black);

        add(txt);
    }
    else
        txt.text = e.getX();

    //and the same for Y

}
```

Hope that helps